# Ubuntu 22.04 developed a data leak from about 19/05/23?

Tags: 22.04, cron, dropbox, data-loss, anacron

I am using a data limited ISP so data usage matters.

From about 19/05/23 22.04 (Jammy) seem to have started using 100M of data every (very approximate) hour.

I have rig with several flavours of Ubuntu and I have noticed this problem extends to 20.04 (Focal) too although I don't know when it started for this one. My setup is multiple OS with a common home mount point.

I know there are several unattended uploads of data that occur so I have tried to switch these off with the following: -

#!/bin/bash

```
sudo systemctl status clamav-freshclam.service
sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam.service
sudo systemctl status cron
sudo systemctl stop cron
sudo snap refresh --hold
sudo systemctl disable --now systemd-timesyncd
```

This did not stop it.

I have now just added the following too - but without the former stuff and I think the CRON controller is still activating anacron? I am currently trying both together.

```
sudo systemctl stop anacron.timer
```

Note: That anacron reports for the first run it ran (1) (which I expect) and then (0) after that which is also correct but data is still be consumed. I don't know the problem is these scripts either but suspect it due to the regular data loss of 100M ish.

When it first occurred I completely re-installed 22.04 (jammy) as I have seen something similar before 01/12/22 and it fixed it. This time it doesn't.

I know this is sort of incomplete but I wanted to make the report before I run out of data. :-(

**Edit:**

Thanks for the quick reply. I am sorry I don't know a lot about this and my strategy was to try and turn things off in turn to find the problem. I couldn't think of way to somehow detect a process that is accessing the network for a short time. Yes, leaving stuff turned off is not a wise idea.

I took a look in cat /var/log/apt/history and it reports the first update but not the second or third so its not that.

I have just noted that with the following set the problem persists as I have just lost another 100M.

```
sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam.service
sudo systemctl stop cron
sudo systemctl stop anacron.timer
```

In this case the log reports that anacron was not started.

I can boot the rig and just monitor the data with `vnstat -v` with no additional processes added and it still does it.

snap list --all  gives the following: -

```
Name               Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare               1.0                         5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core               16-2.58.2                   14784  latest/stable    canonical✓  core,disabled
core               16-2.58.3                   14946  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18             20230320                    2721   latest/stable    canonical✓  base,disabled
core18             20230426                    2745   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20             20230404                    1879   latest/stable    canonical✓  base,disabled
core20             20230503                    1891   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core22             20230503                    634    latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  198    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  194    latest/stable    canonical✓  disabled
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3               90     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3               93     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.6f39565               140    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.6f39565               137    latest/stable    canonical✓  disabled
gnome-42-2204      0+git.587e965               102    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-81-g442e511             1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-79-ga83e90c             1534   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
snap-store         41.3-71-g709398e            959    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store         41.3-66-gfe1e325            638    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
```

I am not sure what I can do with this?

I am currently running from 20.04 (Focal) as its the first time I have tried a different OS from 22.04(Jammy) where I first noticed the problem.

Any idea where to go next?

---

I think I have this resolved thanks to Sebastian's suggestion to run `nethogs`. Thanks Sebastian. Do I need to tick some like boxes somewhere?

The problem seems to be the DrxxBxx (well known cloud storage firm) daemon which I have now disabled and things are back to normal but without my cloud memory synchronisation.

I don't know why it was doing this though but I don't use it much and am happy to just use it from its web interface. I am pretty certain I was testing with the synchronisation turned off and anyway this tends to be immediate when it engages. If it is not related to synchronisation I can't imagine what else it might be doing. I have checked the web based account and I couldn't find evidence that security had been breached but I am not an expert.

I couldn't work out how to take the daemon off completely but the icon menu does allow you to stop it and you can set a configuration tickbox before you do this to stop it restarting on the next boot.

When I re-installed 22.04 I did not load a new version of the daemon but used the one I installed last time. There does seem to be two versions of the daemon available for 22.04 from their web interface but I have not tried either yet to see if it fixes the problem. I would also need to do this for the other OS I use. (18.04, 20.04 & 22.04).

Comment: Your question contains very little information about the actual troubleshooting you have been doing - instead you have disabled random services, which seems like an inherently bad idea. Maybe for starters include output of `cat /var/log/apt/history` and `snap list --all`.

Comment: Also, since I'm using Ubuntu Server, and not experiencing this, you can rule out anything that's present on Ubuntu Server (i.e. the problem must be exclusive to Ubuntu Desktop) - that means `cron`, `timesyncd` etc. In general, services like this don't generate much traffic, so it's unclear why you would suspect this in the first place.

Comment: There is a tool called `nethogs` that you can use to monitor network bandwidth quite easily. Let it run for a while to see which processes generate the most traffic.

Comment: @Sebastian you should add that as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool called `nethogs` to monitor bandwidth usage easily. Just install it using apt.

It can show throughput per second as well as cumulative traffic per process. Cycle through the different display modes by pressing `m`. Let it run for a while to see which processes generate the most traffic.